# How can I install python packages permanently when I am running my code as a python shell in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express, web-development-server

I am trying to install modules like cv2 and nmpy, found a few solutions but using them the installation takes places every time the shell is used which increases the response time.

This is the function in nodeJS I am using to call the python function

```
`app.post("/img", (req, res) => {
    callNumber(req,res);
});
function callNumber(req,res){
    var spawn= require('child_process').spawn;
    var process = spawn('python',    
    ['./saved_model_exec.py',req.body.imgURL]);
    process.stdout.on('data',function(data){
    res.send(data.toString());
})
}`
```

This is the python file I am trying to run

```
`import tensorflow as tf
 import cv2
 import numpy as np
 import sys
 model = tf.keras.models.load_model('mnist.h5')
 img = cv2.imread('test.png', 0)
 img_resized = img.resize(28, 28)
 img_resized = np.array(img)
 img_reshaped = img_resized.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
 img_reshaped = img_reshaped/255.0
 res = model.predict([img_reshaped])[0]
 digit, accuracy = np.argmax(res), max(res)
 print(str(digit))`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install` to install your python packages before running your nodejs code.
See [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) on how to instal pip if you already don't have it on your system.

Eg of using pip to install numpy: `pip install numpy`

If you're using the same instance for both python and nodejs:

- Add a requirementx.txt file alongside the python file
- Install dependencies using a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) before launching the nodejs process

Comment: That works on my PC but not when I host it on the cloud, using pip install just installs it in the python directory in the C drive, any ideas how I can use this directly on the server?

Comment: You should install the dependencies on the instance you're hosting on the cloud. Does the suggestion make sense?

Comment: I am not sure if I can do that, I am deploying my app on heroku and according to what I found I can only do that if it's running python as in using django or something similar. Idk how to implement python dependencies with express framework in nodejs. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Please update your post with details of setup. Make sure you include the following details:

Are you deploying the nodejs and python applications on the same instance?

Is your python code a django application?

Do you have a `requirements.txt` file for your python application?

Comment: I am trying to use the same instance, the python file that I am trying to run I have added in the question, would you suggest that I should use another instance and run a django server there to run this file and link it with the nodejs server?

Comment: Add a `requirementx.txt` file alongside the python file and install dependencies . Use a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) to install your dependencies before launching the nodejs process.